# How to optimize Python code for faster downloading

Tags: python, pandas

I have below code which runs fine in Python and what it does is download some timeseries datapoints. Only problem is it takes hours to download. How can I fix this using multithreding or any other functionality for faster download? my excel list has 187 ids to be read

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('ids.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
x=[]
x.append(df['external_ids'].to_list())
dfdps = client.datapoints.retrieve_dataframe(external_id=x[0],start=0,end="now")
```

Comment: I don't know if using `pd.read_excel()` instead of `pd.ExcelFile().parse` makes any difference?Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: What is *client* ?

Comment: its my own sdk..used mainly for authenticatinng

Comment: I'm guessing here... So you have an Excel spreadsheet containing a number of IDs. Unless the spreadsheet is massive, then your dataframe construction will be very fast. What I suspect is that the files you're downloading are very large. The rate at which you can acquire these files will be constrained by the bandwidth of the server on which they reside and your own internet/broadband capacity. You could consider multithreading but if the delay is due to constraints on your inbound bandwidth then that's not going to help

Comment: can you just post it as an answer with some steps on how we do it as multithreading. your assumption is right to an extent. i would be preferring a way where I take 5 or 10 ids from my excel at a time run it and in next turn I take the next five Ids. Is it possible to do such a way?